# getResourceAsStream giving null

Tags: java, servlets

I have written a servlet class for my local Tomcat7 server to upload a file into a folder named "temp" that is within the project root folder. The java file that contain the servlet class also contains an another class named PdfRenderer. After uploading the file to the temp folder, servlet class create a object of PdfRenderer and calls a method of that PdfRenderer object. That method contains a line

```
PdfRenderer.class.getResourceAsStream("/temp/" + fileName));
```

where fileName is the uploaded file.

This line of code creating some exception. I think getResourceAsStream is giving NULL here. Though the file is uploaded correctly and it is available in the temp folder. I have tried using system based absolute address i.e. /var/lib/tomcat7/Webapps/test-app/temp/fileName. But till it does not change anything.

What should I do? Please suggest. Please ask if further information requirred.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` gets resources from the classpath, loaded by the class loader.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what `getResourceAtStream` does. I would suggest that you read the documentation.

Comment: Is it so even when I am using "/" infront of the filepath? @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: It is **always** so. That is not a file path, it is a classpath path.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to resolve myself. Thanks for replying.